# Node.js API with express & mysql - Search for multiple values in search parameter

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

My current query looks like this:

```
router.get('/search?', function(req, res, next) {
    var title = req.query.title;
    var sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE title = ?"; 
    connection.query(sql, [title], function (error, results, fields) {
        res.json({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results});
    });
});
```

It works if I enter:

```
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/search?title=mr
```

But how can I search for multiple values with OR ... like this:

```
localhost:4001/api/v1/users/search?title=mr,mrs,dr
```

Comment: Are you planning to search for partial matches or full matches?

Comment: ... mmh ... I in this case full match

Answer (score 2):

Basically,

If you have multiple comma separated values in a query parameter, you can split them by `,` and use the sql `IN clause`.

If you have a single parameter value then your method already works fine.

```
router.get('/search?', function(req, res, next) {
    var title = req.query.title;
    var sql;
    if (title.includes(",")) {
        var params = title.split(",");
        sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE title IN " + params;      
    } else {
        sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE title = " + title;      
    }
    connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
        res.json({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results});
    });
});
```

Comment: ... is there any way to also bind it .... or is it fairly save like shown?

Comment: i did not quite get what you are saying.

Comment: Well ... isnt't  ... sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE title = " + title; ... a bit unsafe? ... and rather use placeholders '?' ? https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs_cmd.asp?filename=demo_db_where_placeholders